# What is the best way to create an offline backup of a git project (Unreal Engine)?

Tags: git, backup, commit, repo, git-history

I've just started using Git and GitLFS for version control on game projects that I'm making with the Unreal Engine. These projects use a lot of large binary files and so they're expensive to store on an online server for long periods of time.

Accordingly, I want to make offline backups of my project that contain all files and assets. This is for general backup purposes during development, and also for longer-term backup, e.g. when I have a project that I've finished working on for the time being, but might want to pick back up later.

From what I currently understand, one option is to clone my repository to a new location on my desktop PC, then literraly just delete the (hidden) .git folder from that new cloned version of the repo, and then zip the project folder. I can then delete the remote repository. When I want to continue development, I can unzip the folder I zipped up, open gitbash, and run "git init" to start a new repo. However, that obviously won't restore my old branches or commit history.

Is there an alternative way of backing up a repository if I want to keep alive things like the branches and commit history?

I've considered whether the correct approach is simply to clone the remote repo straight to the backup drive. However, I don't know what would happen if I then deleted the remote repo. Could I simply create a new remote repo and then associate it with my local backup repo by opening GitBash in the backup folder and calling e.g. "git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here" ?

Comment: Yes, you can keep local .git files and delete remote repository, and later on associate your local repo (including all commit history) with any remote repository and continue development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup a copy of your folder containing your git project, that's it. Later if you want to have it on a new remote repository you could change your remote:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
```

If you worked only locally you add the remote:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
```